# Batch file script to parse and edit large block of text

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have a text file where a very long block of text, usually around 600 alpha-numeric characters (no spaces), is the only contents of the file.  I need to parse that block of text and do a sort-of-hash thing and then push that hashed text into a variable.

Example:

codeblock.txt contains a character string "12345678ABCDEFGH" (though in reality it will be random characters with ~600 character length).

"12345678ABCDEFGH" needs to be parsed by a batch file and then "hashed" by reversing the characters in four-character chunks.  So "12345678ABCDEFGH" becomes "43218765DCBAHGFE" and that info is then pushed to variable "HASHVAR".

The code I have only parses the data "as is". I'm stuck on how to manipulate it the way I need it to.

This is what I have so far:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (c:\temp\codeblock.txt) do set rawvar=%%i
```

Thoughts?  Is this doable in a batch file?

Comment: Your question is too vague; can you share your research and what you've done so far? Take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can do this in batch. Show your code if you have a code issue.

Comment: The code I have only parses the data "as is".  I'm stuck on how to manipulate it the way I need it to.  This is what I have so far:

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (c:\temp\codeblock.txt) do set rawvar=%%i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Swap Characters in String

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%I in ("12345678ABCDEFGH") do set "RAWVAR=%%I"

set "START=0"
:FlipLoop
set "TEMPVAR=!RAWVAR:~%START%,4!"
set /a "START+=4"
if defined TEMPVAR set "HASHVAR=%HASHVAR%%TEMPVAR:~3,1%%TEMPVAR:~2,1%%TEMPVAR:~1,1%%TEMPVAR:~0,1%"
if defined TEMPVAR goto FlipLoop

echo HASHVAR = %HASHVAR%
pause
endlocal
```

Output:

```
HASHVAR = 43218765DCBAHGFE
```

Comment: Yep, this worked for me.  I substituted my text file path for "12345678ABCDEFGH" in LINE 4 and it did just what I needed it to.  Thanks so much!